# as3 Adobe device TouchEvent Test

Tags: actionscript-3, air, device

Can you test touchEvent on Adobe Device Cental, google it can't find any information. I know you can do multi touch, but single Touch doesn't seem to work... Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You need to set the Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#inputMode

Comment: WOW is that it!!!! I TRY IT NOW

Comment: is trace still work under TouchEvent?

Comment: yah should be all good... so you know I'm not sure how this will work in the debugger... one sec I'll do some poking around myself as well, but I know that needs to be set for touchpoints to be picked up, otherwise they just come through as mouse events

Comment: I tried that, and only MouseEvent got detected, and none of the TouchEvent was trigger, sick of complie and run on devices...

Comment: yah debugger doesn't pick it up device does

Comment: o OK I C, how poor is that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#inputMode

Doesn't show mouse click events in the debugger as touch points does register them when run on a device.

Also to note you can use mouse click events which do still work fine even after enabling multi-touch mode:

```
            addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchBeginHandler);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, touchBeginHandler);
```

Comment: yeah i tried that it doesn't pick it up, it still get all the mouseEvent not touchEvent... any suggestion i could be done wrong. i have import the correct class and have that line in the init();